# Why My ReactJs Loop Dropdown List call many times automatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const App = () => {
const [num, setNum] = useState();
const [name, setName] = useState();
const [moves, setMoves] = useState();


    useEffect(() => {
    async function pokemonAPI() {
        const getPokemon = await axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${num}`);
        console.log(getPokemon.data.name);
        setName(getPokemon.data.name);
        setMoves(getPokemon.data.moves.length);
    }
    pokemonAPI();
    

 // this function call many times automatically how can I fix this.  

    **function dropDown() { // this function call many times itself
        for (var y = 0; y <101; y++) {
            document.getElementById("100dropdown").innerHTML += ("<option value =" + y + " >" + y + "</option>");
        }
    }
    dropDown();**   
});

// its works fine on first reload of page but when i choose any number this function call it many times 

return (
    <>
            <div className="main_div">
            <h1 className="choose_value">
                Please Choose your <strong>  Pokemon </strong> Value <br />
                <select name="100dropdown" id="100dropdown" value={num} onChange={(event) => {
                    setNum(event.target.value);
                }}>
                 
                </select>
            </h1>
            <div className="pokemonList">
                <h1>You've choose <span style={{ color: 'green' }}> {num} </span> value</h1>
                <h1>Your Pokemon is <span style={{ color: 'red' }}> {name}</span></h1>
                <h1>Your Pokemon has <span style={{ color: 'blue' }}> {moves}</span> moves </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Format your code properly, its really hard to understand how the code is structured.

Comment: You set the state in useEffect without dependencies, it rerenders the component, reruns the effect and so on...

Answer (score 2):

## Issue

The `useEffect` is missing dependencies, so it triggers the effect callback every time the component renders. `pokemonAPI` updates state so a new render is triggered each time. This creates a render loop, so `dropDown` will also be called each render.

Additionally, I don't see any reason why `dropDown` should be declared in the `useEffect` at all. It's rendering static data and mutates the DOM, which is an anti-pattern in React.

## Solution

Fix the dependencies, add `num` that is used in the GET request, and remove `dropDown` function:

```
useEffect(() => {
  async function pokemonAPI() {
    const getPokemon = await axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${num}`);
    console.log(getPokemon.data.name);
    setName(getPokemon.data.name);
    setMoves(getPokemon.data.moves.length);
  }
  pokemonAPI();
}, [num]); // <-- add dependency array!
```

If you need to run the effect more than this then add any missing dependencies your linter may also complain about.

Compute and render the select options in your JSX inside the element with `id="100dropdown"`.

```
<select
  name="100dropdown"
  id="100dropdown"
  value={num}
  onChange={(event) => setNum(event.target.value)}
>
  {Array.from({ length: 100 }, (v, i) => i)).map(i => (
    <option key={i} value={i}>{i}</option>
  ))}
</select>
```

Comment: but when add ***'' dependency array [ ]''*** and choose any number then I can't fetch API data. if I pass the ***[num]*** it works dropdown fine but it also can't fetch data

Comment: @ShamshadHussain I think that `num` was included in my comment about adding any dependencies the linter complains about, but updated my answer to explicitly call it out. Also updated to suggest more optimal solution to rendering the select options.

Comment: @ShamshadHussain Welcome! Has my answer been able to help you resolve your question/issue?

Comment: yes sir your answer solve my problem thanks